# Structure for a strategy game

Tags: c++, software-engineering, sdl, rts

I am making a strategy game like Age of Empires. It's a pretty big project and I need a clear game structure.

I have defined a `Game_Object` class with variables such as:

- `Hit Points`
- `Speed`
- `Damage`
- `Range_Attack`
- ...and a few functions to move the game object, load the game object to the screen, check collisions, etc.

Inheriting from this `Game_Object` class are:

- `Building_Object` (It is buildings in the game to train soldier and villager)
- `Dynamic_Object` (It is dynamic objects such as villager, soldier, elephant, bird

I have defined a `Civil` class, it is a class about the country. It contains:

- a `std::vector<Game_Object*> GameObject` containing game objects
- variables to store the number of resources
- a few variables about technology
- functions to check the amount of army units, villagers, houses
- a few functions to check collisions, update the game objects, move game objects

I have defined a `Civil_Computer` class, which inherits from my `Civil` class. It has a few functions to control the nation of the computer opponent.

I also have defined a `Manager` class, to load the map to the screen, load image, manage game objects, etc. It has `std::vector<Civil*>` containing the nations of AI and human players, a few function to initialize the game window, check winning, load game object to the screen, etc.

Finally, I have a header file to define many functions such as `Move_Object`, `Check_Alive`, etc.

Can someone suggest to me a clearer structure?

Comment: There's more than 1 way of solving things/tasks and whether your solution is good or not good, and whether it can be solved in a better way, is up to discussion and is based on personal opinions, which this site isn't really about. You should try implement your solution and if you have any issues along the way, feel free to edit your question to aim it against that specific problem and we will be here to help you out.

Comment: FWIW, having `Building_Object` and `Dynamic_Object` classes is discouraged nowadays, because how will you make an caravan object that can move *and* create villagers? (Age of Mythology ran into this problem with its "mirror towers", which are actually dynamic objects whose speed is set to 0, and some custom levels give them a non-zero speed, leading to silly results)

Comment: Thanks for that, do you have a solution for it?

Comment: I think my answer to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-organize-a-game-engine-in-c-is-my-use-of-inheritance-a-good-idea/23148#23148 is probably relevant here.